# Многострочный ввод с клавиатуры в WinApi

Tags: winapi, c++

Возник вопрос, какой элемент управления диалогового окна нужно использовать в WinApi, чтобы иметь возможность вводить текст обраом, аналогичным компоненту TMemo в приложениях с формами.
Пытался использовать Rich Edit Control, однако он не позволяет вводить несколько строк.

Comment: А Вы точно правильно rich edit используете? Т.к. многострочный текст он понимает... Возможно проблема в том, что энтер перехватывается какой-либо кнопкой диалога

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Просто я только начал его изучение и не выставил свойство "Требуется возврат". Спасибо.